# Single producer multiple consumers C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to implement a program that consists of a producer thread adding objects to a `std::vector` and multiple consumer threads removing objects from the same vector until it's empty. I am using a `condition_variable` to let the consumers know that new objects have been produced. Problem is that in last iteration (n items left in storage where n is number of consumer threads), consumer threads get stuck waiting on a conditional variable, even though that condition should not be met (`storage` is not empty -> at least that's what I figured with some debug logs).

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#define CONSUMER_COUNT 4
#define STORAGE_SIZE CONSUMER_COUNT * 10000

class Foo {
private:
  int _id;

public:
  Foo(int id) : _id(id) {}
  int getId() const { return _id; }
};

std::vector<Foo> storage;
std::mutex storageMutex;
std::condition_variable storageCV;

void Producer(int limit) {
  for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{storageMutex};
    storage.emplace_back(Foo(i));
    storageCV.notify_one();
  }
  storageCV.notify_all();
}

void Consumer(int id) {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul{storageMutex};
    storageCV.wait(ul, []() { return !storage.empty(); });
    if (storage.empty())
      return;
    storage.pop_back();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<std::thread> consumers;
  consumers.reserve(CONSUMER_COUNT);

  auto producer = std::thread(Producer, STORAGE_SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMER_COUNT; ++i) {
    consumers.emplace_back(std::thread(Consumer, i));
  }

  producer.join();
  for (auto &consumer : consumers)
    consumer.join();

  storageCV.notify_all();

  std::cout << "[MAIN] Done!" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Storage is left with " << storage.size() << " items!"
            << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried adding a simple boolean flag that producer will toggle once it's done with adding all of the items, but then I am not sure (logically) how should I set the condition in consumer threads. Simply adding that check on top of current one is not enough because then a thread might stop running even though there are still some items in the storage.

Comment: I don't see how consumers can get stuck with non-empty `storage`. But they will definitely get stuck with empty `storage` - once all the items are consumed, they'll just wait forever, and the main thread will block on `consumer.join()` . `if (storage.empty()) return;` is dead code; `storage` can't be empty at that point.

Comment: Add that stop-flag-checking condition to the lambda of `wait`. A consumer should wait only if both the queue is empty and the stop-flag is false. Note that the stop-flag needs to be updated under the locked mutex.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks, that's what I figured in the meantime, everything is okay now :) Btw, is it okay (is there any potential downside) to use the same mutex (as the one I use for managing state of my storage for updating this flag?

Comment: @ZlatanRadovanovic AFAIK, you have to use the same mutex. Since a condition variable can wait on a single mutex only.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, the problem is that consumers get stuck. The problem is here:

```cpp
storageCV.wait(ul, []() { return !storage.empty(); });
if (storage.empty())
    return;
```

Note that `std::condition::variable::wait(lock, condition)` is just a convenience function, and this code is equivalent to:

```cpp
while (storage.empty())
    storageCV.wait();
if (storage.empty())
    return;
```

It's easy to see that the conditional `return` is pointless, because when we reach it, the condition is always false.
The condition would need to be inside the loop to have any effect.

These adjustments are necessary:

1. We have to modify this loop so that it's possible for a consumer to not wait infinitely.
2. The producer thread has to wake up any currently waiting consumers once all the elements have been processed.
3. It's possible that a consumer thread is currently:

   - right before `while (storage.empty())`, or
   - right before `storageCV.wait()`

   ... so it is not going to be woken up by `notify_all()`, because it's not waiting yet, but is about to. We have to repeatedly `.notify_all()` to wake up every thread, even those that are not waiting yet.

#### Changes to Producer

```cpp
// We create an atomic counter to keep track of how many
// consumers remain.
// When this hits zero, the producer can stop notifying the
// remaining consumers.
std::atomic_int consumer_stop_counter;

// The producer needs to receive the number of consumers from the main thread.
// It wouldn't be safe to communicate this via an atomic counter which
// is modified by the consumers, because it's possible that the producer
// is done pushing all of its items to storage before any consumers
// "register themselves".
// In such a scenario, the producer would think that there are no
// consumers that need to be notified anymore and all works has been completed.
void Producer(int limit, int consumers) {
  for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{storageMutex};
    storage.emplace_back(Foo(i));
    storageCV.notify_one();
  }

  consumer_stop_counter = 0;
  while (consumer_stop_counter < consumers) {
    storageCV.notify_all();

    // optional: mitigate effects of busy wait
    std::this_thread::yield();
  }
}
```

#### Changes to Consumer

```
void Consumer(int id) {
  while (true) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul{storageMutex};
    // Transform cv waiting into a regular while-loop.
    while (storage.empty()) {
      storageCV.wait(ul);

      // If we got woken up and the storage is empty, that means that we exit.
      // We hold the lock after calling .wait(), so it is safe to access the storage.
      if (storage.empty()) {
        consumer_stop_counter++;
        return;
      }
    }

    storage.pop_back();
  }
}
```